# Upload multiple images and get url FOR EACH separate

Tags: php, image, upload

Good day dear members!
  i have a question and i hope you will help me. (:
 This is code for upload and display url adress for ONLY ONE IMAGE.
But i need to this code display me separate url adresses from multiple images so i can put them into mysql.

code for 1 image :

```
<form  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload2" id="fileToUpload2"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
                                    <?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imgurl

$fileToUpload = "uploads/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo  $imgurl;
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Help me , edit this code so this code could upload multiple images and display multiple url adresses separate. Thanks )

Comment: So is this answered?

Comment: Where is the problem? You just have to repeat everything you do for `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` with `$_FILES["fileToUpload2"]`...

Comment: I have done that..  but mybe someone can suggest me different and more easy way..